# Is it possible to import js file dynamically in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I need to import a js file dynamically via env. So far I was not be able to do it.
I tried these 2 methods but they are failing.

```
import app from "@/constants/app." + process.env.NODE_ENV + ".js";

const app = () => import("@/constants/app." + process.env.NODE_ENV + ".js");
```

Last one is not failing but output is something different.
In the picture app is my actual js file.
app1 is when I use `const app = () => import("@/constants/app." + process.env.NODE_ENV + ".js");`

Do you know any way to import file dynamically?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: try using relative import instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no solution for that.
So I used env files to solve this problem. https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes
Thanks for help.